# Ошибка: Unable to extract uploader id, не возпроизводит музыку. Discord.py YouTube_dl

Tags: discord.py, youtube-dl

Код

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, *, query):
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if voice_channel:
        await voice_channel.connect()
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        with YoutubeDL({'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{query}", download=False)['entries'][0]
            URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(URL)
            voice.play(source)
    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")

@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.stop()
        await ctx.send("Stopped the music.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("No music is playing.")

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

При выполнении команды !play (название музыки) происходит это:

```
[2023-03-03 20:23:54] [INFO    ] discord.voice_client: Connecting to voice...
[2023-03-03 20:23:54] [INFO    ] discord.voice_client: Starting voice handshake... (connection attempt 1)
[2023-03-03 20:23:55] [INFO    ] discord.voice_client: Voice handshake complete. Endpoint found frankfurt5438.discord.media
[download] Downloading playlist: phonk
[youtube:search] query "phonk": Downloading page 1
[youtube:search] playlist phonk: Downloading 1 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 1
[youtube] zG6NcHtMBHc: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Downloading just video zG6NcHtMBHc because of --no-playlist
ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы решить данную проблему попробуйте обновить  YouTube_dl

```
 pip install --upgrade youtube_dl
```

вы можете попробовать другой метод для  извлечения видео

```
    info = await bot.loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{query}", download=False))
URL = info['entries'][0]['formats'][0]['url']
```

Comment: У меня установлен и обновлен youtube_dl но все равно эта ошибка

Comment: вы можете попробовать другой метод для  извлечения видео                                                       info = await bot.loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{query}", download=False))
URL = info['entries'][0]['formats'][0]['url']